# How to sign AuthnRequest using Apache mod_mellon module

Tags: apache, saml

we have requirement to sign SAML AuthnRequest before sending to IDP. we are using **Apache module mod_mellon for SAML implementation**. As per documentation we added below attribute in SP metadata xml file, but still request is not being signed.

**AuthnRequestsSigned="true"**

below SP metadata for reference.

```
<EntityDescriptor entityID="https://foo.com" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC.....</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://foo.com/mellon/logout"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://foo.com/mellon/postResponse" index="0"/>
</SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

request is still not signed when we access application. can someone help if they came across similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signature is created with a private key and not with a public key.

The SP meta data is not used here.

You need to define the private key in mellon configuration

E.g.

```
MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/ssotest.key
```

Please see https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon

Comment: Hi, i have defined private key in mellon.conf file. and it's being loaded by apache.                    
                Require valid-user
                AuthType "Mellon"
                MellonEnable "auth"
                MellonVariable "cookie"
                MellonSPMetadataFile /opt/httpd/conf.d/sp-metadata.xml
                MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /opt/httpd/conf/server.key
                MellonSPCertFile /opt/jboss/httpd/conf/server.crt
                MellonIdPMetadataFile /opt/jboss/httpd/conf.d/idp-metadata.xml